# Footer will not stick to the bottom

Tags: css, footer

I've tried following the tutorial found [here](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) 
to get my footer to stick to the bottom of the browser window. I've checked the tutorial several times and it seems I have the right structure in place. However my footer still hovers about 30px above the window. Been stuck on this for a couple of days and i'm all of out ideas so any help would be great :)

```
<div class = "wrapper">
  <div id='cssmenu'>
  </div>


  <div id="header">
    <h1>My header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">Some content
  </div>
  <div class="push">
  </div>
</div><!-- end wrapper -->


<div class="footer">Footer with images
</div>



* {
margin: 0;
}

html, body {
height: 100%;
}

body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
background-color: #FCFDFF;
font-size: 18px;
}

.content
{
  padding: 0% 0% 0% 20%;
  width: 65%;
  line-height:1.7em;
  background-color: #FCFDFF;

}


.footer, .push {
height: 4em;
clear: both;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #000;
}

.footerImages {

padding: 5px 5px 5px 1px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: What's your markup look like? the same? This demo's footer happens to work because they have a enough content to keep it seemingly at the bottom of the window. You want yours always stuck to the bottom - no matter what?

Comment: @Evan, I've tested the demo, and it works to keep in the bottom on large screens.

Comment: @ Gull, his demo doesn't work, but the one he provided does. It's using min-height + negative margin on the wrapper that equals the height of the footer to keep it at the bottom. And what he's posted is missing this. `.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -155px;
}`

Answer (score 3):

Why not just do

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

That will give you a footer that sticks to the bottom of the window, which is what you want based on your question.

Comment: Just make sure to have adequate padding at the bottom of your body / wrapper / container class to match the height of the footer to avoid overlapping.

Comment: I would give you a thumbs up but I don't have over 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Your missed the `.wrapper` css content:

```
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
```

it will only work if the wrapper has this info.
Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8g5h5fe5/